# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined ( popupWindow.top.close();)

Tags: javascript, php, popupwindow

I have a script like

```
if(typeof json.content[0].redirects != 'undefined'){
    if(json.content[0].redirects != ''){  
        popupWindow = window.open(json.content[0].redirects, "Window2", "width=1000,height=800,scrollbars=yes,left=200");
        var p = window.parent.document;
        p.onclick = function(){
            popupWindow.top.close();
        }; 
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly in `localhost`.
But in live popup window appears, but no data and it displays an error:

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined'.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Is expected result to close `top` `window` ?

Comment: I'm not sure but try this `popupWindow.offset().top.close()`

Comment: @ guest271314 :yes.it closes in localhost,but this code put into server doesnt work

Comment: @ abhishekkannojia: its not working

Comment: @Sougata: No it doesn't.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia: What's that supposed to do? `popupWindow` doesn't even have an `offset` function.

Comment: Is popupWindow being initialised anywhere before your snippet?

Comment: Then put the var keyword before popupWindow. The issue is that you are not initialising popupWindow so it is undefined

Comment: @ danbahrami: is this is not enough??                                                                                          popupWindow = window.open(json.content[0].redirects, "Window2", "width=1000,height=800,scrollbars=yes,left=200");

Comment: It depends how strict your environment is

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can check if the popupWindow is triggered like this:

```
if (popupWindow.length) {
 popupWindow.top.close();
  //...continue to close popup windows
}else{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: I wasn't the person who down voted you but FYI, this method will throw an error if popupWindow is not initialised. A better method is to check typeof popupWindow !== "undefined"